# Geometrical Explanation of Borsuk Theorem

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Assume $K$, $L$ are $n$-pseudomanifold, and $K$ is compact. Let $f$ be a simplicial map between $K$ and $L$. We denote $n$-simplexes of $K$ and $L$ by $S_n(K)$, $S_n(L)$. Define
$$\deg_2f:=\text{#}\{\sigma\in S_n(K)|f_\text{#}(\sigma)=\tau\}\mod 2$$
and $\tau\in S_n(L)$.

> **Borsuk Theorem** Let $f$ be an antipode-preserving map. Then $\deg_2f=1$.

We think about the lower dimensional cases. For computing the degree of antipode-preserving map between $\mathbb S^1$, we can trangulate it as a diamond, denoted by $K$. For there is always a simplicial approximation $g:Sd^m K\to K$ of $f$, which is also antipode-preserving.

My problems are

- I can not figure out why 
  $$\text{#}\{\sigma\in S_1(Sd^m K)|g_\text{#}(\sigma)=\tau\}$$
  is odd.
- How about the higher dimensional cases by using this combinatorial method.

Any advice is helpful. Thank you.